# Logstash remove lines with Grok

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

My plan is to filter a log-file for a specific IP with Logstash.

I started with a simple IP-filter which should delete all lines which a non valid IP and be removed afterwards.

```
grok {
match => [ "ip_filter" , " %{IPV4:clientip}" ]
tag_on_failure => [ "_todelete" ]
}
```

So every line with a non valid IP should be tagged _todelete, but on Kibana I see every line tagged with it. Any ideas why?

My next step would be to delete all lines with the tag "_todelete" with

```
grok {
     remove_tag => [ "_todelete" ]
  }
```

which leads me to a "_grokparsefailure"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you can add some of your sample logs it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Just if anybody needs the answer too: The problem was that grok was looking for a space before the IP. In my case the line started directly with the IP so my solution was to use

^%{IPV4:clientip}

Comment: this is not true, grok doesn't look for a space. You need to show your log to full understand what was the actual cause of the problem. Without a sample log, this answer is useless to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a condition based on the tag to control if the line is send to your ES output in your logstash file.

Try something like this:

```
output {
    if "_todelete" not in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
        index => "index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

adding this condition should filter the unwanted lines and not output them to you ES index.